# SwiftUI - Add a row of multiple Textfields/Views on button click

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am using `SwiftUI` to build a feature where a user can click on a button to create rows and each row has multiple views (Textfields, Radio buttons...) [see image below]
I created a swift class `DynamicSkills` where I handle the creation of the items and the "Add" button, but when I click "Add" the App crashes completely, below is my code so far and an image showing how it should be, I just started with SwiftUI and I am not fully grasping the concept of `Binding<>`.

What should I do exactly to get it up and running?

[image]

```
//DynamicSkills.swift
struct SkillListEditor: View {

    @Binding var evalList: [String]
    @Binding var skillList: [String]

    func getBindingS(forIndex index: Int) -> Binding<String> {
        return Binding<String>(get: { skillList[index] },
                           set: { skillList[index] = $0 })
    }

    func getBindingE(forIndex index: Int) -> Binding<String> {
        return Binding<String>(get: { evalList[index] },
                           set: { evalList[index] = $0 })
    }


    var body: some View {
        ForEach(0..<skillList.count, id: \.self) { index in
            ListItem(skillEvaluation: getBindingE(forIndex: index), text: getBindingS(forIndex: index)) { self.skillList.remove(at: index) }
        }
        AddButton{ self.skillList.append("") }
    }
}

fileprivate struct ListItem: View {

    @Binding var skillEvaluation: String
    @Binding var text: String
    var removeAction: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Spacer().frame(height: 8)
            HStack{
                Button(action: removeAction) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                }
                TextField("Skill", text: $text)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0))
                    .cornerRadius(6)
            }
            HStack{
                Text("Evaluation").font(.callout)
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack{
                RadioButtonField(id: "1", label: "1", isMarked: $skillEvaluation.wrappedValue == "1" ? true : false) { selected in
                    self.skillEvaluation = selected
                }
                Spacer()
                RadioButtonField(id: "2", label: "2", isMarked: $skillEvaluation.wrappedValue == "2" ? true : false) { selected in
                    self.skillEvaluation = selected
                }
                Spacer()
                RadioButtonField(id: "3", label: "3", isMarked: $skillEvaluation.wrappedValue == "3" ? true : false) { selected in
                    self.skillEvaluation = selected
                }
                Spacer()
                RadioButtonField(id: "4", label: "4", isMarked: $skillEvaluation.wrappedValue == "4" ? true : false) { selected in
                    self.skillEvaluation = selected
                }
                Spacer()
                RadioButtonField(id: "5", label: "5", isMarked: $skillEvaluation.wrappedValue == "5" ? true : false) { selected in
                    self.skillEvaluation = selected
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct AddButton: View {

    var addAction: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            Button(action: addAction) {
                    Text("add skill").padding(.horizontal, 12).padding(.vertical, 6).background(.white).foregroundColor(Color("PassioGreen")).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(Color("PassioGreen"), lineWidth: 2))
                }
        }.padding(.top, 14)
    }
}
```

And in my main screen in `ContentView` I am showing it this way:

```
//ContentView.swift

@State var skills = [String]()
@State var skillsEvals = [String]()

struct ContentView: View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            HStack{
            Text("Skills").font(.headline)
            Spacer()
        }
        HStack{
            Text("Add up to 5 skills").font(.callout)
            Spacer()
        }
        SkillListEditor(evalList: $skillsEvals, skillList: $skills)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update: this is the custom radio button class CustomRadio.swift**

```
//Custom Radio button used:
struct RadioButtonField: View {
    let id: String
    let label: String
    let isMarked: Bool
    let callback: (String)->()

    init(
        id: String,
        label:String,
        isMarked: Bool = false,
        callback: @escaping (String)->()
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.label = label
        self.isMarked = isMarked
        self.callback = callback
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action:{
            self.callback(self.id)
        }) {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(label).foregroundColor(self.isMarked ? .white : .black).bold().padding(.horizontal, 8).padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .background(self.isMarked ? Color("PassioGreen") : Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0))
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum I added the custom radio field I am using (the numbered row) this should be enough to be reproduced, unless I am not understanding the "Minimal Reproducible Example" correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AddButton` action appends an item to `skillList`, but does not append an item to `evalList`. So when `ListItem` uses its `skillEvaluation` binding, the binding's getter tries to access an element of `evalList` that doesn't exist.

Try this:

```swift
AddButton {
    self.evalList.append("")
    self.skillList.append("")
}
```